# HTML Input Radio Value="false" Posts NULL

Tags: html, forms, post, input, types

In FireFox, I have a radio input with it's value set to the string "false" (not sure if there's any possible distinction from boolean false).

```
<input name="test_1" type="radio" value="false" />
```

When I post the form, I get:

```
print_r($_POST["test_1"]);

Array
(
    [test_1] =>
)
```

Which suggests that the browser casts the string "false" to Boolean FALSE or NULL.

1. What is the expected behavior?
2. What if I specifically want the string "false" to be returned?

Comment: Are you 100% sure the radio is checked when you submit it? By the way, instead of guessing you can use `var_dump()` to get the value's type. Only in Firefox? You tested other browsers?

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is that if the radio button is checked the value is POSTed otherwise an empty string is sent. In your case if the radio button is checked "false" will be sent otherwise an empty string is sent.

Comment: yup, if it is not check a value will/should not be posted